# Cant implemet Twilio StatusCallback

Tags: android, twilio

I am creating a sample twilio sms app.I can send sms by button click in the app.But What I need is how to get the status of sended message and toast it.I know it is the statuscallback of twilio.But how to implement that.

**My Code Portion**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send=findViewById(R.id.send);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build() );
    }

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            String url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+"AC*********************"+"/SMS/Messages";
            String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("AC*********************"+ ":" + "df55**********************").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("From", "+123456789")
                    .add("To", "+1847085532")
                    .add("Body", "hello test")
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .header("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.d(TAG, "sendSms: "+ response.body().string());

            }catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }



        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StatusCallBack function works through a webhook, i.e. an internet-accessible URL on your server that Twilio can call, with the details of the status of the message sent. In your case, you seem to be sending message through a mobile app. You need to standup your own backend server that can listen to incoming status-callback requests from Twilio and communicate them to your mobile device appropriately.

StatusCallbacks in Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-java

Comment: Bro i just want this for testing purpose.How to implement statuscallback in abouve code?ie; without using backend?.

Comment: Backend is must, to integrate with Twilio!